# Is there a way to let VBScript work further even if macro which was called is not yet finished?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am calling directly **VBA Macro** from **VBScript**. The **VBA Macro** guides the user to **Internet Explorer window pop-up**, whereby the user is required to enter his login credentials.

[image: pop-up window]What I am trying to achieve is to **getElementbyName** from the HTML of this **pop-up** and insert the values in the input field.

After getting the pop-up window, **VBScript** however **does not continue working** until I **close** respective excel file and pop-up window. I looked for the solution in the internet but did not find anything useful for that. *Is there any workaround which will allow me to put the pop-up window on hold and let VBScript get element by ID in the pop up?*

Here is my current VBScript Code -

```
xlsm_file_name = "webADI_template_Bankbuchungen_GL.xlsm"
'opening xlsm file and setting readonly to false
set xlobj = createobject("Excel.Application")

xlobj.Visible = TRUE
xlobj.Workbooks.Open("webADI_template_Bankbuchungen_GL.xlsm")
xlobj.Application.Run "'webADI_template_Bankbuchungen_GL.xlsm'!Sheet1.BneUploadCommon"
' from this moment VBScript does not go further until I manually close the excel file 
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Document.getElementsByName("unamebean")(0).value = "niko"  

xlobj.quit
```

**EDIT:**

I found out what causes VBScript to stop and not go further with next lines. Macro which is called in VBScript involves a long-lasting process of data accumulation with switching between functions and classes.

So at the moment of **window pop-up**, **macro is not finished**, as there are other father processes waiting behind for user's input.

I found in the forums, that to ensure that process happens on the background and the **VBScript goes further**, one may use **WshShell Run** - ***maybe a sensible solution would be to call Macro from Shell?*** - I did not manage to find the way to do that however.

***Is there a way to let VBScript work further even if Macro which was called is not yet finished?***

Comment: *"for security purposes I am not allowed to share the picture of log-in credentials but I will share the properties of the pop-up window"* - What is the point in that image?

Comment: I am just trying to make the question as descriptive as possible. But thx, if picture does not bring any value, I will delete that.

Comment: The login credentials are obviously something you shouldn't share but can you not share an image of the login popup without the credentials entered?

Comment: please see the update :)

Comment: How is the login popup triggered can you share some of the code?

Comment: The VBA code is not my own property. Unfortunately, I cannot share it.

Comment: In which case you won’t be able to get to the DOM. Likelihood is the login form uses a WebBrowser control to show the HTML content, without access to the WebBrowser Control I can’t see how you'll be able to access it. It should be possible to inject some values using `SendKeys()` though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that, my VBScript does not go further until I close the pop-up window and stop VBA procedure. I would like to know if it's possible to go further with VBScript while having the VBA code on hold. Hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, first, you want to login to the website i.e. entering username and password, and then, you want to run some other code in VBScript without closing the login popup. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kalicharan.N I am calling vba macro first, which creates this login pop up. I need to be able to enter login details and then let the macro run further. However, the problem is that VBScript does not proceed until macro is finished - I.e. data entered or pop up closed

Comment: Can you add a code `Thisworkbook.close()` at the end of your actual vba code, after all the operations? this will close your workbook and completes the execution, once your VBA macro completes its run. You may need to add `Application.Displayalerts=False` before closing the workbook. This is to suppress all the save confirmation popups which usually thrown up by excel.

Comment: @Kalicharan.N the problem is that pop-up is only the middle of the macro. So I need to pause macro, and let vbscript do its changes and then let macro go further

Comment: You are trying to achieve multithreading in VBA/VBS, but VBA is single threaded programming language. We cannot manage 2 different program instances at the same time. Whatever code you want perform, you can place it all under one VBA module and give a try. I.e. Place the vbscript code (that you want to run after login popup) in the excel macro itself.